# Diferenças entre listeners e adapters no swing

Tags: java, swing, adapter, listener

Quando se está programando interfaces gráficas em java usando `swing`, sempre nos deparamos com ambos os tipos, principalmente para atribuir e criar eventos a partir de ações de botões ou outros componentes.

Apesar de mexer há algum tempo com `swing`, sempre tive curiosidade sobre a diferença entre listeners e adapters, e como se substituem em alguns casos como o exemplo abaixo:

> Evento de teclado em um `JTextField` com `Adapter`:

```
    jTextField1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            super.keyReleased(e);
        }
    });
```

> Evento de teclado em um `JTextField` com `Listener`:

```
    jTextField1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    });
```

A interface listener obriga a implementar alguns métodos, e o adapter apenas os necessários.

Com base nisso, quais diferenças(caso haja outras) entre `Listeners` e `Adapters` dentro da API do swing? Como saber quando é mais vantajoso usar um ou outro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em resumo, `adapter` é um padrão de projeto onde uma classe implementa uma interface anulando (deixando sem operações) os métodos da interface e você apenas sobrescreve os métodos que te interessam, com as operações que te interessam.

Já no `listener`, por ser uma interface, você é obrigado a implementar todos os métodos, mesmo os que não te interessam.

Você pode ver detalhes sobre o pattern [Adapter aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter).

Se você precisa/consome apenas um método (comportamento) o `adapter` é a melhor opção. Se você tem problemas com herança múltipla, o `listener` é sua melhor opção.

**Atualização 21/02/2016**

Veja o seguinte exemplo:

Você quer que quando o usuário clique no X de fechamento de janela, uma mensagem de confirmação seja exibida ao usuário. Onde ele pode desistir de fechar a janela.

Para um caso desses, você deve implementar a interface [WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html). Note que a interface define 7 métodos, mas você está interessando apenas no método [windowClosing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowClosing-java.awt.event.WindowEvent-). Implementado a interface, você teria que implementar os 7 métodos. Para esse cenário, você pode (ou deve) usar uma implementação da classe [WindowAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html), que é abstrata.

A documentação da classe diz:

> An abstract adapter class for receiving window events. The methods in this class are empty. This class exists as convenience for creating listener objects.

Que em tradução livre significa:

> Uma classe adaptadora abstrata para receber eventos de janela (window events). Os métodos nessa classe são vazios (sem implementação). Essa classe existe para criar ouvintes (listeners) de objetos de maneira mais fácil.

Nessa situação, você iria sobrescrever apenas o método [windowClosing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html#windowClosing-java.awt.event.WindowEvent-) da classe [WindowAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html).

Note que a classe `WindowAdapter`, implementa mais 3 interfaces, além da `WindowListener`, justamente com a intenção de minimizar código. Em outras palavras, `adaptar` os listeners.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Quem implementa quem? Não ficou muito claro, e como a pergunta foi mais especifica dos adapters do swing. se possivel, gostaria que a resposta fosse mais voltada a eles.

Comment: Oi @DiegoF, adicionei um exemplo. Espero que ajude.

Comment: A resposta já está completa, mas seria interessante você adicionar a tradução da citação em inglês, para usuários que não dominam a língua inglesa, terem um bom entendimento.

Comment: Adicionei a tradução. Acho que ajudará. Saudações.