# O que é e como implementar um Listener em java?

Tags: java, listener

Apesar de já ter perguntado as [Diferenças entre listeners e adapters no swing](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114260/28595) e também se [Listeners são uma implementação de Observer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125624/28595), gostaria de uma explicação mais detalhada a respeito.

O que são listeners no java? Como implementar um?

Comment: No Android [usa-se muito Listener](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html), e eu ainda faço confusão a respeito disto, se é algo restrito do Java ou algum tipo de padrão que pode ser implementado em outras linguagens. De qualquer forma, a pergunta é bem interessante, então segue minha contribuição +1

Comment: Downvote, além de negativar, por que você não contribui com a pergunta, citando o que pode ser melhorado nela?

Comment: Você quer implementar Listener para algo proprio, ou quer implementar em algo existente? Penso eu que Listener se refere aos eventos de um objecto, sendo que o objeto pode receber multiplos eventos do mesmo tipo, então pensando em algo simples, você teria que ter o registrador de eventos na interface da "classe" e um trigger para cada tipo de evento, a ação/trigger acontece como e quando você desejar, por exemplo se o objeto for "destruido" poderiam haver eventos para chegar isto, ou se alterar uma variavel do objeto você emitiria um "trigger".

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento queria saber como eu implemento um listener, o que é preciso pra eu cria-lo.

Comment: @Articuno posso lhe mandar um pseudo-codigo? Estou meio sem pratica pra responder e paciencia xD

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sem problemas :) o que eu queria é entender o conceito na pratica, coloquei java pra pergunta nao cair em ampla demais.

Comment: Analogicamente o Listener serve como visão, audição, tato, olfato e paladar. Para cada ação, uma reação (claro se você criar uma programação para isso). Sentiu um cheiro de café, vá logo pra cozinha buscar. hehe

Comment: @Articuno isto não é um exemplo java nem nada https://pastebin.com/BjthmL51, em java existem classes que auxiliam nisto, a ideia é apenas lhe explicar em um código simples a ideia. Eu criei dois tipos de eventos `baz` e `bar`, no caso o `bar` especificamente é disparado quando executa `changeFoobar()`, se você precisar saber quando a tarefa que cuida do `changeFoobar()` executa-la para informar a outro tarefa, poderá registrar um evento chamado `obj.on("bar", function () { ... });`...

Comment: ... pode na verdade registrar vários eventos `obj.on("bar", function () { ...informa ao joão que alterou o status... });`, pode na verdade registrar vários eventos `obj.on("bar", function () { ...informa a maria que alterou o status... });`, isto tudo é como disse, um pseudo-codigo para exemplificar, existem classes no java que implementam facilmente ouvintes para um objeto. Assim que possivel, se ninguem lhe fornecer um exemplo eu vou arriscar um, é que não tenho tanta habilidade com esta linguagem.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o que seria esse `push`?

Comment: @Articuno é o que adiciona uma function ao array especificado, aonde ficarão registrados os eventos baz ou bar

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### O Padrão Observer vai muito além do Java e do Swing

Como você já viu, ["Listener" e "Observer" são nomes diferentes para o mesmo padrão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/125634/68989), e, ele pode ser utilizado para diversas coisas além da utilização no Swing, e, pode ser implementado em diversas outras linguagens.
Dentro do Java, por exemplo, o sistema de bindings do JavaFX utiliza (internamente) o padrão Observer ao fazer bind entre as *Properties*, o que permite a uma Property ser alterada (atualizada) quando outra é; e esse sistema pode ser usado mesmo em softwares sem Interface Gráfica (você pode usufruir das Properties e bindings mesmo sem uma GUI).

### Porque utilizar o Padrão Observer

É comum o uso desse padrão quando você quer que um determinado código seja executado (o código do observador) quando determinada coisa acontecer (o evento) em algo (esse "algo" é a coisa observada, que pode ser por exemplo, um Botão na Tela).

Também é comum a utilização desse padrão para atualizar dados automaticamente (que é o caso das Properties e Bindings do JavaFX); nesse caso, você pode ter uma implementação que garante até mesmo a coerência dos dados a partir dessas atualizações automáticas.

- Por exemplo, você pode ter um atributo `dataDeNascimento` e um atributo `idade` dentro de um Objeto `Pessoa`, e, fazer com que, quando o valor em `dataDeNascimento` for alterado, o valor em `idade` seja **automaticamente atualizado**, afim de garantir que a `idade` **sempre** corresponderá corretamente à data de nascimento. Assim, se você chamar `setDataDeNascimento(...)` e em seguida chamar`getIdade()` obterá a idade já atualizada (mas tome cuidado com problemas de concorrência, para não ler dados ainda não atualizados ou, no caso de longas estruturas de dados sendo atualizadas, não acabar lendo a estrutura enquanto ela ainda está "atualizada pela metade").

### Exemplo de utilização do Padrão Observer

O Código abaixo é uma implementação simples para exemplificar o Padrão Observer:

```
public class Observado {
    private Object atributoQualquer;
    private final List<Observador> observadores = new ArrayList<Observador>();

    private void notificarObservadores() {
        for (Observador observador : observadores) {
            observador.notificar(this);
        }
    }
    public void adicionarObservador(Observador obs) { //também chamado de addListener(...)
        observadores.add(obs); //"obs" passará a ser notificado sobre mudanças em this
    }
    public void removerObservador(Observador obs) { //também chamado de removeListener(...)
        observadores.remove(obs); //"obs" deixará de ser notificado sobre mudanças em this
    }
    public void setAtributoQualquer(Object novoValor) {
        atributoQualquer = novoValor;
        notificarObservadores(); //avisamos os Observadores que houve uma alteração em this
    }
}

public interface Observador { //também chamado de "Listener"
    public void notificar(Observado obs); //também chamado de "notify()"
}

public class ObservadorA implements Observador {
    public void notificar(Observado obs) { //Chamado quando ocorrer uma alteração em "obs"
        //Atualiza dados, executa código que deve ser executado quando "obs" for alterado, etc.
        //Aqui dentro pode-se chamar GETTERS de "obs" para obter os novos dados em "obs", como chamar "obs.getAtributoQualquer()"
    }
}
```

Tendo o código acima, ainda é necessário registrar o `ObservadorA` como um observador do `Observado` para que ele possa ser notificado quando o `Observado` for alterado, podemos fazer isso assim:

```
Observado observado = new Observado();
observado.adicionarObservador(new ObservadorA());
```

Pronto, dessa forma o método `notificar(...)` do `ObservadorA()` será chamado quando o `observado` for alterado (alterado ao chamar-se `setAtributoQualquer(...)`).

**Considerações sobre este Exemplo:**

- Fiz um método `notificar(Observado obs)`, esta assinatura de método faz com que o Observador tenha que "puxar" (*pull*) os dados de `obs` para poder saber o que foi alterado e quais os novos valores em `obs`, isto faz-se chamando os GETTERS de `obs`.
- O método poderia ser, por exemplo, `notificar(Object novoValor)` ou `notificar(Observado obs, Object novoValor)`ou ainda `notificar(Observado obs, Object novoValor, Object valorAnterior)`, qualquer um desses estaria "empurrando" (*push*) os dados para o Observador, para que ele não tenha que chamar os GETTERS de `obs`.
  <sub>Nota: a assinatura `notificar(Observado obs, Object novoValor, Object valorAnterior)` é semelhante a assinatura do método `changed(...)` da classe `ChangeListener` do JavaFX:

   [`void changed(ObservableValue<? extends T> observable, T oldValue, T newValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html#changed(javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue,%20T,%20T))</sub>
- É comum que os "Observados" permitam adicionar "Observadores" para diferentes tipos de eventos/alterações, assim, você irá encontrar métodos como `addXXXXListener()`, `addYYYYListener()`, etc. (por exemplo, `addFocusListener(...)`, `addActionListener(...)`, `addMouseListener(...)`, etc.). Isso permite criar códigos para "ouvir" (ou "observar") coisas diferentes, sem ter que ouvir/observar tudo o que acontece no objeto Observado.
- Também é muito comum criar-se *Classes Anônimas* e, mais recentemente, *Expressões Lambda*, no lugar de criar Classes Observadoras/Listeners, isso reduz a quantidade de código, e é usado diretamente nos métodos `addXXXXListener(...)`. Exemplos:

  - `botao.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //Classe Anônima
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Clicado!");
        }
    });`
  - `botao.addActionListener(e -> { System.out.println("Clicado!"); }); //Lambda`

O JavaFX possui um sistema Observer que é muito interessante, e que vai muito além do que apresentei aqui, recomendo muito [estudá-lo](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/package-summary.html).

Comment: Excelente resposta! :D

Answer (score 0):

Se traduzirmos a palavra Listener para o português teremos a palavra "Ouvinte". Ouvinte na língua portuguesa é definido como "Aquele que ouve".

## E agora na programação?

Podemos defini-lo como ouvinte também, por que ele fica *como se estivesse atento a todas ações do usuário*.

Ele fica a espera, como se estivesse filtrado todos os dados gerados pelo usuário (Movimentação do mouse, clique no mouse, tecla pressionada...), para então tomar a atitude definida.

Se fôssemos atribuir sinônimos a função Listener seria atribuido as seguintes palavras:

- Ouvinte
- Receptor
- Espectador
- Auxiliador
- Observador

Talvez devido a extensão do assunto recomendo ler atentamente a seguinte matéria que abrange bem isso.

http://www.devmedia.com.br/javalisteners-trabalhando-com-actionlistener-e-keylistener-em-java/31850

Exemplo de uma interface Listener:

```
public interface EventListener {
    void fireEvent (Event e);
}
```

Um vídeo que talvez também seja de ajuda para a criação seria este:
https://youtu.be/-ATbC-4rhc4

Listener possuí algumas peculiaridade s que torna difícil explicar pela escrita.

Comment: E um exemplo de como implementar?

Comment: Não pode ser um exemplo mais simplificado nao? Essa classe ta meio dificil de entender.

Comment: @Articuno Está mais simples?

Comment: Até demais, não entendi como implementar com esse exemplo. O que eu gostaria é ver como eu posso criar um listener do zero, o que eu preciso fazer para ele funcionar corretamente.

Comment: @Articuno https://youtu.be/-ATbC-4rhc4 Acredito esse ser bem esclarecedor, e está em português:)

Comment: Vou transformar esta resposta em uma wiki, talvez torne mais fácil encontrarmos uma melhor explicação

Comment: O problema do video é que ele nao agrega a sua resposta. Imagina se alguem cair nessa pergunta e não le comentários, ou se o video for apagado? O ideal é ter a explicação na resposta, ela deve ser independente de sites e links externos.