# Pra que serve o ActionListener?

Tags: java, swing, javafx, gui, awt

Estou começando a estudar Java.

Alguém pode me explicar, **detalhadamente**, do modo mais completo e simples possível,  pra que serve o método `actionListener` do Java (`da lib swing`).

Pois estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade pra entender,por isso gostaria de exemplos práticos de como usar tal método.

Comment: Seja bem vindo: isto te ajudaria? [O que é e como implementar um Listener em java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/236123/o-que-%C3%A9-e-como-implementar-um-listener-em-java/236183)

Answer (score 1):

Listener, no java, é uma forma de implementar o padrão de padrão de projetos “Observer”.

Assim sendo, o Listener serve para escutar o que acontece em um objeto e havendo alguma mudança de estado, outro(s) objetos é(são) avisado(s). Ou seja, sua função é "ouvir" alterações que ocorram no objeto que está sendo monitorado.

Dito isto, ActionListener é uma interface Listener que exige a implementação de apenas um método, o actionPerformed(ActionEvent e), que é responsável por realizar uma determinada ação quando for disparado  um ActionEvent (um evento qualquer). Por exemplo, no componente JButton é possível registrar um ActionListener para ele, de modo que ao sofrer um clique, um ActionEvent é realizado, assim chamando o método actionPerformed do ActionListener, consequentemente realizando a rotina que você definiu para o método.

Enfim, o ActionListener é utilizado para ouvir ações realizada em determinados componentes (como cliques de botão) e tomar alguma decisão lógica baseado nesta ação. Assim, possibilitando atribuir funcionalidades à botões ou algum outro componente.

Como sugestão de implementação, consulte este link: https://www.devmedia.com.br/java-listeners-trabalhando-com-actionlistener-e-keylistener-em-java/31850